# Como uso uma variável no lugar da chave do Array?

Tags: javascript, json

Sou novo com manipulação de JSON, estou com uma duvida.
tenho uma Array:

```
let json = [
    {
        "id": 111111,
        "name": "nome1"
    },{
        "id": 222222,
        "name": "nome2"
    }
]
```

Como faço para passar o nome da chave como um parametro de uma função?

Exemplo:

```
teste = (json, key) => {
    console.log(json[0].key); // "key" é minha variável, que vai receber a string "id"
}

teste(json, 'id');
```

Eu quero que nesse caso acima retorne `111111`.

```
teste(json, 'name');
```

E nesse caso acima retorne `name1`.

Comment: Isso aí não é um JSON, é um objeto Javascript, são coisas bem diferentes. E não tem como você usar uma propriedade "key" se não existe "key" no objeto (afinal, você tem só as posições numéricas, e as chaves "id" e "name". Importante [edit] o post e esclarecer melhor qual a dificuldade exatamente (se é isso que eu disse, qual resultado esperava, essas coisas). - Se quer usar a variável, ponha entre colchetes

Comment: Se for o  `id` de um dos elementos do array que você deseja usar deve ser algo parecido com isso: `console.log(json[0]['id']);`

Comment: Vai dar certo com "key" se tirar as aspas: console.log(json[0][key]);

Comment: @Bacco, demorei para entender...nesse caso `console.log(json[0][key]);` sendo `key` o parâmetro contendo a string `id`.

Comment: "Cris e Rafa", editei a pergunta para tentar deixar mais clara, verifique se ficou correta. PS: Se vcs são duas pessoas, criem contas separadas. As regras do site não permitem contas coletivas.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que você está usando o ".key" literalmente, então estará se referindo a um elemento "key":algumacoisa que não existe.

Use a variável como índice (sem aspas) para resolver:

```js
var objeto = [
    {
        "id": 111111,
        "name": "nome1"
    },{
        "id": 222222,
        "name": "nome1"
    }
]

var key = "id";

console.log(objeto[0][key]); //sem aspas, "key" é variável

console.log(objeto[0]['id']); //com aspas, "id" é a chave

console.log(objeto[0].id); //literal
```

**Observação importante:** isto que você tem no código é um **objeto** e não um JSON. JSON é uma String em "formato de objeto JS", é uma especificação. O Objeto já é uma estrutura da linguagem.